# PHP's error levels

Tags: php

The only [error level in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) that will halt the script but can be caught and dealt with have to be triggered with the trigger_error() function correct? I'm referring to the "E_USER_ERROR" error level. The "E_ERROR" error will simply halt the script and I can't do anything about it as the developer.

Answer (score 8):

E_ERROR will simply stop the script.  It's meant to be used for:

> Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted.

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

You cannot handle the following other error types for similar reasons:

- E_PARSE
- E_CORE_ERROR
- E_CORE_WARNING
- E_COMPILE_ERROR
- E_COMPILE_WARNING

[set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) however can handle the follow errors:

- E_WARNING
- E_NOTICE
- E_USER_ERROR (using [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php))
- E_USER_WARNING (using [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php))
- E_USER_NOTICE (using [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php))
- E_STRICT
- E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR

Answer (score 3):

You can catch E_ERROR using a shutdown script

from my posting http://jarofgreen.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/catching-php-errors/

```
register_shutdown_function(‘x’);
function x() {
$error = error_get_last();
if ($error) {
// deal with $error['file'],$error['line'],$error['message'],$error['type']
}
}
```

Comment: Note that you will lose the stack due to the way shutdown functions work. And if you want to catch only E_ERROR with that method (eg because you are using a traditional error handler for the others) you can filter with `if ($error['type'] != E_ERROR) return;`

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own error handling and halt the script and actually do anything you want when an error occurs.

> [set_error_handler()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: Can the set_error_handler() function handle and error with the level "E_ERROR"?

Comment: No it can't, the following levels don't work with a customer error handler: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your driving at or trying to do here, but if you're looking for a way to "catch" and deal with 'errors' - Maybe look into [exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

*From PHP Manual on Exceptions*

> An exception can be thrown, and caught
> ("catched") within PHP. Code may be
> surrounded in a try block, to
> facilitate the catching of potential
> exceptions. Each try must have at
> least one corresponding catch block.
> Multiple catch blocks can be used to
> catch different classes of exeptions.
> Normal execution (when no exception is
> thrown within the try block, or when a
> catch matching the thrown exception's
> class is not present) will continue
> after that last catch block defined in
> sequence. Exceptions can be thrown (or
> re-thrown) within a catch block.